# Fresh Debian Testing - wget returning GnuTLS errors

Tags: debian, wget, ssl

Did a fresh install of Debian 10 and tried to run the following:

```
root@siren:/# wget music-server.net/download/install.sh
--2021-03-08 15:32:18--  http://music-server.net/download/install.sh
Resolving music-server.net (music-server.net)... 73.189.195.198
Connecting to music-server.net (music-server.net)|73.189.195.198|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 308 Permanent Redirect
Location: https://music-server.net/download/install.sh [following]
--2021-03-08 15:32:18--  https://music-server.net/download/install.sh
Connecting to music-server.net (music-server.net)|73.189.195.198|:443... connected.
GnuTLS: A TLS fatal alert has been received.
GnuTLS: received alert [80]: Internal error
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

Tried the following to fix it:

1. Upgraded to Debian Testing
2. Downloaded and installed latest wget explicitly adding openssl support
3. wget google.com works just fine

wget works fine on my other systems, so seriously no idea what is going on here. It works fine on another fresh install of Debian from the same exact flash drive.

Additional

Installed openssl from source too.

Comment: There's no SSL certificate on [73.189.195.198:443](https://73.189.195.198/), that's not a `wget` issue.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore this error (expired,invalid,not trusted ... certificat) use `--no-check-certificate` option:

```
wget --no-check-certificate music-server.net/download/install.sh
```

the same option can be used with `wget2`:

```
sudo apt install wget2
wget2 --no-check-certificate music-server.net/download/install.sh
```